# how to Add boolean array to a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

public boolean addSubClass(Week week, int startTime, int endTime, boolean[] weekNumber) {

```
    boolean result = false;

    boolean repeat = false; 

    if (repeat != true) {
        SubClass s = new SubClass(week);
        s.updateTime(startTime, endTime);
        s.updateTime(weekNumber);
        subClassList.addLast(s);

        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

situation: this is part of my code. I got 3 differnet startTime, endTime and weekNumber in my file, when I check for first startTime and endTime, these integers are added into the list successfully, but when I check for the weekNumber, it always get the Last one that on the list.
question: can I add boolean array into the linked list???

Comment: You might want to tell us a bit more about your problem, including describing the problem, showing your code, your errors, you know, obvious stuff.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and update your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Great idea and appropriate for this "telepathy required" post, but maybe your page is a little long-winded. May I suggest a savagely abbreviated bullet-point version that can be absorbed in a few seconds (consider the attention span of someone who needs such advice) with link(s) to the (current) full version.

Comment: Sorry, we are not telepathic. Yo'll just have to give us more info. Maybe post a brief code snippet.

Comment: @Bohemian: Feel free to write such a page. I'd rather try to meet the needs of people who are actually willing to put in a bit of effort. If someone isn't going to take the time to *read* some text about writing a good question, what chance is there that they'll put in the larger amount of effort it takes to write a genuinely good question?

Comment: @JonSkeet We could go back and forth on this, but in brief I'd be happy if they just read a *small* excerpt, put in *some* work, and wrote an *OK* question. That's all some people are capable of/willing to do. But even that would be an improvement over the rubbish we too often see.

Comment: @Bohemian: As I say, there's nothing stopping you from creating such an excerpt. Of course, new users are likely to have already seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to start with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java a `LinkedList` (or any other generic collection, for that matter) can only contain elements of the same *type*. In your question it seems (you should post the code) that you have a list of Integers, and that's the only type of objects you can add to the list: Integers. With `addLast` you can't add an array of booleans; not even an array of Integers, only a single `Integer`.

What you could do for adding several items of the same type at the end of the list, is using `addAll`, like this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list2.add(3);
list2.add(4);
list1.addAll(list2); // now list1 has elements [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: can you look at my code now and please tell me how to add the boolean array, thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Generic Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) tutorial.

In this case, `T` is replaced with `Integer`. Attempting to add anything other than an `Integer` instance to the collection will result in a compilation error.